# UITableView section border

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there any way to set a border on a UITableView section (group style)? I don't mean change the border on the cells in the section - I want a border around the whole section. Like this:

[image: Bordered UITableView section]

**Note**: While the picture above only shows part of a single section, the table in question actually has multiple sections, each of variable lengths, which I would like to border separately.

Comment: got the answer? @Shaun

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can achieve it with couple of line of codes :

Simply have the TableView in your Xib file.**No need to have the UITableView Style to Grouped.**

1) Import the QuartzCore framework in your .h file.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

2) Now set the Layers of the TableView in .m file.

```
[CategoryTblView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
[CategoryTblView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[CategoryTblView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[CategoryTblView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
```

**And this is the output :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, this will put a border around the whole table. However, I have multiple dynamic-length sections which I wanted to border separately (I have updated the question to reflect this). I no longer need to do so (the style has been changed), but I'm still curious about if it is possible.