# iOS 7 TableView like in Settings App on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios7

I want to have a group UITableView with the style same like the iPad Settings application **Detail view** for **iOS 7**.

It is a tableView with rounded corner. Please check the attachment for details.

Is some default settings to make it look like that or we need to do some custom drawing for the same.

Any hint in right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 200, accepted):

I've gone ahead and further customized the willDisplayCell to get a better simulation of the cell styles in the settings app.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
        if (tableView == self.tableView) {
            CGFloat cornerRadius = 5.f;
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
            CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
            CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);
            BOOL addLine = NO;
            if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
                CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
            } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
                addLine = YES;
            } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            } else {
                CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds);
                addLine = YES;
            }
            layer.path = pathRef;
            CFRelease(pathRef);
            layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.8f].CGColor;

            if (addLine == YES) {
                CALayer *lineLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
                CGFloat lineHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
                lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds)+10, bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width-10, lineHeight);
                lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor;
                [layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
            }
            UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
            [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
            testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
            cell.backgroundView = testView;
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("tintColor"))){
        if (tableView == self.tableView) {
            let cornerRadius : CGFloat = 12.0
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            var layer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            var pathRef:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
            var bounds: CGRect = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 25, 0)
            var addLine: Bool = false

            if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)-1) {
                CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius)
            } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds))
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius)
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds))
                addLine = true
            } else if (indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)-1) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds))
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius)
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds))
            } else {
                CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds)
                addLine = true
            }

            layer.path = pathRef
            layer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 0.8).CGColor

            if (addLine == true) {
                var lineLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
                var lineHeight: CGFloat = (1.0 / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
                lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds)+10, bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width-10, lineHeight)
                lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor
                layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
            }
            var testView: UIView = UIView(frame: bounds)
            testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)
            testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            cell.backgroundView = testView
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let pathRef = CGMutablePath()
    let bounds = cell.bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 0)
    var addLine = false

    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        pathRef.__addRoundedRect(transform: nil, rect: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadius, cornerHeight: cornerRadius)
    } else if indexPath.row == 0 {
        pathRef.move(to: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
        pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY), radius: cornerRadius)
        pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
        pathRef.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        addLine = true
    } else if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        pathRef.move(to: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
        pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY), radius: cornerRadius)
        pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
        pathRef.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
    } else {
        pathRef.addRect(bounds)
        addLine = true
    }

    layer.path = pathRef
    layer.fillColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.8).cgColor

    if (addLine == true) {
        let lineLayer = CALayer()
        let lineHeight = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
        lineLayer.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX + 10, y: bounds.size.height - lineHeight, width: bounds.size.width - 10, height: lineHeight)
        lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
    }

    let testView = UIView(frame: bounds)
    testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
    testView.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.backgroundView = testView
}
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (cell.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIView.tintColor))){
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 12.0
            cell.backgroundColor = .clear
            let layer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let path: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
            let bounds: CGRect = cell.bounds
            bounds.insetBy(dx: 25.0, dy: 0.0)
            var addLine: Bool = false

            if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == ( tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1) {
                path.addRoundedRect(in: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadius, cornerHeight: cornerRadius)

            } else if indexPath.row == 0 {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
                path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY), radius: cornerRadius)
                path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))

            } else if indexPath.row == (tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1) {
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
                path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY), radius: cornerRadius)
                path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))

            } else {
                path.addRect(bounds)
                addLine = true
            }

            layer.path = path
            layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8).cgColor

            if addLine {
                let lineLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
                let lineHeight: CGFloat = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
                lineLayer.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX + 10.0, y: bounds.size.height - lineHeight, width: bounds.size.width, height: lineHeight)
                lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
                layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
            }

            let testView: UIView = UIView(frame: bounds)
            testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
            testView.backgroundColor = .clear
            cell.backgroundView = testView
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example on iOS7]

Comment: Very nice.  I added a `cell.indentationLevel = 1;` at the end to liken the indentation a little closer to the Settings App.

Comment: That's such an awesome answer. I still cannot get the top and bottom lines to hide. Any idea? Everything else works perfectly!

Comment: Got it working. setting the separator style of the entire table view to none does the trick. Cheers

Comment: To simplify the code you may also use the
`[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:cornerSize];`

Comment: very nice answer but i got issue with above that when i select cell then it going to view full fill color of cell. i also put selection style NON but it now working:( any buddy help

Comment: I just implemented this code successfully. Thanks! @NitinGohel I had the same issue. I just used the same logic to create another view for the cell's selectedBackgroundView.

Comment: @jvanmetre : thanks for ur answer, worked well, but little prob posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/21328801/1462920. As I posted, I am getting problem after cell selection.

Comment: @jvanmetre Good Answer, Upvoted you. This however seem to cause a problem for disclosure icon. My disclosure icon goes outside the cell. Can you please help

Comment: @gaijin how did you set cell selected background view??please tell me yar.it has become a life problem.

Comment: @NarasimhaiahKolli, I posted my code in an answer below. Hope it helps.

Comment: How can you add a colored border line around each group?

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! Works like a charm!! But you should add to the answer that is required to import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: How to set the autoresizing of the layer, so after rotate, it can change the frame like it's superview?

Comment: @jvanmetere right side of  some cells are not rounded when they are displayed initially.They are rounded only on the next reload. Any help ?

Comment: Thanks works great... just a lil change for ios 8  BOOL addLine = NO;
            if (!CGRectGetHeight(bounds)) {
                return;
            }

Comment: is there any thing that should be done befor using the code above?

Comment: @iOSdev check my answer below.

Comment: For me it seems like when i scroll past the first cell and come back to it the rounded corners are gone.

Comment: thanks worked for me but what if I need to add section header also in this group having corner radius

Comment: Anyone give me idea how to give a shadow for this card

Answer (score 19):

In iOS 13 and up, this table style is finally made available by Apple, without having to re-engineer it, with the new [UITableView.Style.insetGrouped](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/insetgrouped) table view style.

In Xcode 11 and up, this can be set in the interface builder settings for the table view, by selecting Inset Grouped for the Style:

[image: Interface builder table view settings]

Comment: Any idea how to set this property for List in SwiftUI ?

Comment: .listStyle(GroupedListStyle()) @SorinLica

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @jvanmetre is great and it works. Building on top of it and as suggested by @SergiySalyuk in the comments. I've update the code to use UIBezierPath instead making it simpler to understand and slightly faster.

My version also fixes the separator bug and adds a selected background view that fits with the cell.

*Remember to set your table view to no separator: `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`*

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  // Set transparent background so we can see the layer
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;

  // Declare two layers: one for the background and one for the selecetdBackground
  CAShapeLayer *backgroundLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  CAShapeLayer *selectedBackgroundLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

  CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 0, 0);//Cell bounds feel free to adjust insets.

  BOOL addSeparator = NO;// Controls if we should add a seperator

  // Determine which corners should be rounded
  if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
    // This is the only row in its section, round all corners
    backgroundLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7, 7)].CGPath;

  } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    // First row, round the top two corners.
    backgroundLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7, 7)].CGPath;
    addSeparator = YES;

  } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
    // Bottom row, round the bottom two corners.
    backgroundLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7, 7)].CGPath;

  } else {
    // Somewhere between the first and last row don't round anything but add a seperator
    backgroundLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:bounds].CGPath;// So we have a background
    addSeparator = YES;
  }

  // Copy the same path for the selected background layer
  selectedBackgroundLayer.path = CGPathCreateCopy(backgroundLayer.path);

  // Yay colors!
  backgroundLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.8f].CGColor;
  selectedBackgroundLayer.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

  // Draw seperator if necessary
  if (addSeparator == YES) {
    CALayer *separatorLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat separatorHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    separatorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds)+10, bounds.size.height-separatorHeight, bounds.size.width-10, separatorHeight);
    separatorLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor;

    [backgroundLayer addSublayer:separatorLayer];
  }

  // Create a UIView from these layers and set them to the cell's .backgroundView and .selectedBackgroundView
  UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
  [backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:backgroundLayer atIndex:0];
  backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
  cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;

  UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
  [selectedBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:selectedBackgroundLayer atIndex:0];
  selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
  cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;

}
```

Comment: Hey @donkey, amazing answer, I want to ask you though if I create the last cell to be dynamic height adjusting to the content of a textview inside, it appears that the rounded part of the cell is not updating also, do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Answering @NarasimhaiahKolli, on how I set the background view of the cell so that whole cell doesn't look like it's highlighted. Hope this helps.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    InfoCell *cell;
    ...

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [self backgroundCellView:cell indexPath:indexPath tableView:tableView];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        UIColor *cellColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.90f alpha:.95f];
        CAShapeLayer *layer = [self tableView:tableView layerForCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withColor:cellColor];

        CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);

        UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
        [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        cell.backgroundView = testView;
    }
}

- (UIView *)backgroundCellView:(InfoCell *)cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    UIColor *cellColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [self tableView:tableView layerForCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath withColor:cellColor];

    CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
    return testView;
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView layerForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGFloat cornerRadius = 5.f;
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);
    BOOL addLine = NO;
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
        CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
    } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
        CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
        CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
        addLine = YES;
    } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
        CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
        CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
    } else {
        CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds);
        addLine = YES;
    }
    layer.path = pathRef;
    CFRelease(pathRef);
    //        layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    layer.fillColor = color.CGColor;

    if (addLine == YES) {
        CALayer *lineLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        CGFloat lineHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds)+10, bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width-10, lineHeight);
        lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor;
        [layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
    }

    return layer;
}
```

Comment: nice... so you have to make another layer for background. If I create another bgView and reuse the same layer do not work, I see.

Comment: There is a white line at the bottom of the cell when you select the cell.

Answer (score 4):

After trying some of the answers here, I decided to go whole hog and implement an entire subclass on top of `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` to replicate the rounded grouped table view style in iOS 7.

https://github.com/TimOliver/TORoundedTableView

[image: TORoundedTableView]

It ended up being a very involved process:

- I had to subclass `layoutSubviews` in `UITableView` to relayout each cell and accessory view so they were no longer edge-to-edge.
- I had to subclass `UITableViewCell` in order to to remove the top and bottom separator hairline views (but leaving the ones inside the section untouched).
- I then created a custom `UITableViewCell` background view that could optionally have rounded corners on the top and bottom to be used for the first and last cells in each section. Those elements had to be `CALayer` to avoid `UITableView`'s implicit behaviour of changing the color of the background views when a user taps the cell.
- Because they are now `CALayer` instances that don't respond to `layoutSubviews`, I then had to do some Core Animation tinkering to ensure the top and bottom cells resized at the same speed as the other cells when the user rotates the device.

All in all, it's possible to do, but since it requires a fair bit of effort and costs a small amount of performance (as it's constantly fighting Apple's code trying to set everything back), it might best to file a radar with Apple requesting they officially expose that style. Until then, feel free to use my library. :)

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to achieve the same Settings app rounded look on the tableviewcells. My answer is also based on a SO answer for [how to set cornerRadius for only top-left and top-right corner of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13163693/1394020).

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setClipsToBounds:YES];

    // rowsArray has cell titles for current group
    NSArray *rowsArray = [self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[rowsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    float cornerSize = 11.0; // change this if necessary

    // round all corners if there is only 1 cell
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && [rowsArray count] == 1) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath;
        maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(cornerSize, cornerSize)];

        CAShapeLayer *mlayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        mlayer.frame = cell.bounds;
        mlayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        cell.layer.mask = mlayer;
    }

    // round only top cell and only top-left and top-right corners
    else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath;
        maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(cornerSize, cornerSize)];

        CAShapeLayer *mlayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        mlayer.frame = cell.bounds;
        mlayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        cell.layer.mask = mlayer;
    }

    // round bottom-most cell of group and only bottom-left and bottom-right corners
    else if (indexPath.row == [rowsArray count] - 1) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath;
        maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(cornerSize, cornerSize)];

        CAShapeLayer *mlayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        mlayer.frame = cell.bounds;
        mlayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        cell.layer.mask = mlayer;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Korey, I used this and it worked great with what I have in mind. However, the sides of the round rectangle is too close to the edges of the screen. is there anyway of making the cells smaller (as in thinner)? Many thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a method called `addRoundedCornersWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius ForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` which will create rounded corners at the top and bottom of every section.

The benefit of using the `maskView` property of `UITableViewCell` is that when you select the cell the rounded corners are still visible.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d in Section %d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section]];
    [tableView addRoundedCornersWithRadius:12.0f ForCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)addRoundedCornersWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius ForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger MBRows = [self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1;
    CAShapeLayer    *MBLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    CGRect cellBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height);

    BOOL shouldAddSeperator = NO;

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == MBRows) {
        [MBLayer setPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cellBounds cornerRadius:radius].CGPath];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [MBLayer setPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cellBounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)].CGPath];
        shouldAddSeperator = YES;
    } else if (indexPath.row == MBRows) {
        [MBLayer setPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cellBounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)].CGPath];
    } else {
        [MBLayer setPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cell.bounds].CGPath];
        shouldAddSeperator = YES;
    }

    [cell setMaskView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds]];
    [cell.maskView.layer insertSublayer:MBLayer atIndex:0];

    if (shouldAddSeperator == YES) {
        CGFloat seperator = (1.0f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        CALayer *cellSeperator = [[CALayer alloc] init];

        [cellSeperator setFrame:CGRectMake(15.0f, cell.bounds.size.height - seperator, cell.bounds.size.width - 15.0f, seperator)];
        [cellSeperator setBackgroundColor:self.separatorColor.CGColor];
        [cell.layer addSublayer:cellSeperator];
    }

    [cell.maskView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell setClipsToBounds:YES];
}
```

---

[image: iOS 9 Grouped UITableView with rounded corners]

Comment: I've added my code to a [Github](https://github.com/berendschot/UITableView-RoundedCorners) repository. I'm even thinking about developing a cocoa pod for this.

Comment: I've mixed your code with the one of @vanmetre (accepted answer) and it fits perfectly to my needs ! +1 for using maskView which allows pretty selection. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great one. Only one problem occurred: I couldn't use the cell.bounds because it was incorrect... Instead of that I created my own bounds from tableView.bounds.size.width and heightForRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 1):

My answer may be too late but for Swift version (any), it will be surely useful and very easy to use it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (tableView == self.tableViewMovies) {
            //Top Left Right Corners
            let maskPathTop = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
            let shapeLayerTop = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayerTop.frame = cell.bounds
            shapeLayerTop.path = maskPathTop.cgPath

            //Bottom Left Right Corners
            let maskPathBottom = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
            let shapeLayerBottom = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayerBottom.frame = cell.bounds
            shapeLayerBottom.path = maskPathBottom.cgPath

            if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 {
                if indexPath.row == 0 {
                    cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerTop
                }else if indexPath.row == 2 {
                    cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerBottom
                }
            }else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 1 {
                if indexPath.row == 0 {
                    cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerTop
                }else {
                    cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerBottom
                }
            }else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 2 {
                if indexPath.row == 0 {
                    cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerTop
                }else if indexPath.row == 2 {
                    cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerBottom
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PS: I have used following code for Swift 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if (tableView == self.orderDetailsTableView)
    {
        //Top Left Right Corners
        let maskPathTop = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
        let shapeLayerTop = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayerTop.frame = cell.bounds
        shapeLayerTop.path = maskPathTop.CGPath

        //Bottom Left Right Corners
        let maskPathBottom = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
        let shapeLayerBottom = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayerBottom.frame = cell.bounds
        shapeLayerBottom.path = maskPathBottom.CGPath

        //All Corners
        let maskPathAll = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight, .BottomRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
        let shapeLayerAll = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayerAll.frame = cell.bounds
        shapeLayerAll.path = maskPathAll.CGPath

        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)-1)
        {
            cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerAll
        }
     else if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
        cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerTop
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)-1)
        {
            cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerBottom
        }
    }
}
```

working code for swift...
what actually we are doing is if section has only one row then we do it on all sides, if section has multiple rows then we do it top on first row and bottom at last row... the properties BottomLeft, BottomRight, topLeft, TopRight should be of type rect corner(Suggestions from xcode when you are typing... there is another property content corner with same name.. so check that )

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. You will have to customize your UITableViewCell's, something like this works:[image]

Set your tableView's style to grouped.

Set your TableView background color to clear color.

On your - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)` make the cell background clear and create a UIView with the desired rounded corners as the background. Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIView *roundedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    [roundedView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:roundedView];


    return cell;
}
```

You might need to do some further polishing, but this is the main idea.

Comment: Given your code, how would you go about changing the width of the cells, or adding margins to the sides of the table?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve the same but with border around each section (line in iOS6). Since I didn't find an easy modification of suggested solutions I came up with my own. It is a modification of the answer @Roberto Ferraz gave in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176179/workaround-for-rounded-corners-of-grouped-uitableview-ios7) topic.
I created a custom class that inherits from UITableViewCell. In it I added a container view with the appropriate size (in my case shrinked on both sides with 15px). Than in the class I did this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    
    CGFloat cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    
    self.vContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    self.vContainerView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.vContainerView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    
    if (self.top && self.bottom)
    {
        // nothing to do - cell is initialized in prepareForReuse
    }
    else if (self.top)
    {
        // cell is on top - extend height to hide bottom line and corners
        CGRect frame = self.vContainerView.frame;
        frame.size.height += cornerRadius;
        self.vContainerView.frame = frame;
    
        self.vSeparatorLine.hidden = NO;
    }
    else if (self.bottom)
    {
        // cell is on bottom - extend height and shift container view up to hide top line and corners
        CGRect frame = self.vContainerView.frame;
        frame.size.height += cornerRadius;
        frame.origin.y -= cornerRadius;
        self.vContainerView.frame = frame;
    
        self.vSeparatorLine.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        // cell is in the middle - extend height twice the height of corners and shift container view by the height of corners - therefore hide top and bottom lines and corners.
        CGRect frame = self.vContainerView.frame;
        frame.size.height += (2 * cornerRadius);
        frame.origin.y -= cornerRadius;
        self.vContainerView.frame = frame;
    
        self.vSeparatorLine.hidden = NO;
    }
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    // establish original values when cell is reused
    CGRect frame = self.vBorderView.frame;
    frame.size.height = BORDER_VIEW_HEIGHT;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    self.vBorderView.frame = frame;
    
    self.vSeparatorLine.hidden = YES;
}
```

Then in your data source you do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    
    // only one cell in section - must be rounded on top & bottom
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1)
    {
        cell.top    = YES;
        cell.bottom = YES;
    }
    // first cell - must be rounded on top
    else if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.top    = YES;
        cell.bottom = NO;
    }
    // last cell - must be rounded on bottom
    else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1)
    {
        cell.top    = NO;
        cell.bottom = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.top    = NO;
        cell.top    = NO;
    }
    
    return cell;
}
```

And voila - you got rounded corners AND borders on your sections.

Hope this helps!

P.S. Made a few edits as I found some bugs in original code - mainly I didn't set all values in all cases which cause some very stunning efects when cells were reused :)

Answer (score 0):

swift 4
In case you want to include the section header also then try below one

declare cornerLayerWidth as global variable

var cornerLayerWidth:CGFloat = 0.0

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let pathRef = CGMutablePath()
    let bounds = cell.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    cornerLayerWidth = bounds.width
    var addLine = false



    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        pathRef.__addRoundedRect(transform: nil, rect: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadius, cornerHeight: cornerRadius)
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 0 {


    }
    else if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        pathRef.move(to: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY))
        pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY), radius: cornerRadius)
        pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
        pathRef.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
    } else {
        pathRef.addRect(bounds)
        addLine = true
    }

    layer.path = pathRef
    layer.fillColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor

    if (addLine == true) {
        let lineLayer = CALayer()
        let lineHeight = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
        lineLayer.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.size.height - lineHeight, width: bounds.size.width , height: lineHeight)
        lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
    }

    let testView = UIView(frame: bounds)
    testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
    testView.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.backgroundView = testView
}
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eMPOIListHeaderViewCell") as! eMPOIListHeaderViewCell

    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    let pathRef = CGMutablePath()
    let bounds =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cornerLayerWidth, height: 50)//cell.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    pathRef.__addRoundedRect(transform: nil, rect: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadius, cornerHeight: cornerRadius)

    pathRef.move(to: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
    pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY), radius: cornerRadius)
    pathRef.addArc(tangent1End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY), tangent2End: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY), radius: cornerRadius)
    pathRef.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))



    layer.path = pathRef
    layer.fillColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor

         let lineLayer = CALayer()
        let lineHeight = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
        lineLayer.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.size.height - lineHeight, width: bounds.size.width , height: lineHeight)
        lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)

    let testView = UIView(frame: bounds)
    testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
    testView.backgroundColor = .clear

    cell.backgroundView = testView


    return cell

}
```

Comment: Not working at my end, Is there any specific property need to keep in mind?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

var top = false
var bottom = false

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if top && bottom {
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        return
    }

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.size.height)
    let corners: UIRectCorner = self.top ? [.topLeft, .topRight] : [.bottomRight, .bottomLeft]

    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
    layer.mask = shape
    layer.masksToBounds = true
  }
}
```

To use:

If the cell is the first of a group, set `top = True`, if it is the last cell, `bottom = true`, if the cell is the only on the group set both to `true`.

If you want more or less rounded, just change the radios from 10 to another value.

Comment: If want to apply shadow and corner radius to first and last cell how can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

This code will set rounded corners for whole table view instead of single cell.

```
UIView *roundedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(table.frame, 5, 0)];
roundedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.8f];
roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
[self.view addSubview:roundedView];
[roundedView release];
[self.view addSubview:table];
```

And clear the background color of each cell in cellForRow

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to remove the top line in the tableview
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.