# how we can get the grouped UITableview style for ios 7 as similar to ios 6

Tags: ios

I am updating my app which will support both ios 6 and ios 7 ,now the problem  is that I need a similar grouped style of tableview for ios 7 as of ios 6.I dont know that how to do this?

Comment: I would suggest you post more detail about what you're wanting.  Getting an iOS7 table is not fundementally different from iOS6.   Is it the "look" you're trying to replicated?  Or is your code not working (if code isn't working you'll need to post it.  You question is too open-ended to get you a useful answer imo.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016313/ios7-uitableview-grouped-like-in-settings-app

Comment: I need same any lucK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 TableView like in Settings App on iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822619/ios-7-tableview-like-in-settings-app-on-ipad)

Answer (score 4):

Achieving this is done by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and overriding its `-setFrame:` method like this:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.origin.x += inset;
    frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539021/how-to-set-the-width-of-a-cell-in-a-uitableview-in-grouped-style)