# Styled Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I saw this on this on the settings section of the Facebook app for iOS7 and I was wondering how the effect of this UITableView is achieved with the margins all around the section. I thought it could be done with UICollectionView with each cell having the look of having 2 or 3 "UITableViewCell's" in it. Is there a better way to achieve this though?

Thanks in advance

[image: Facebook settings screenshot]

Comment: That's how grouped table views looked until iOS 7.

Comment: Yeah, so how do I do this in iOS7 now?

Answer (score 2):

UITableView sections can either be "plain" or "grouped." 
The above is an example of "grouped" sections.

The inset margins were the common design until iOS7. 
That changed along w/other design conventions in order to maximize use of the screen.
Sections in iOS7 can have upper/lower margins with headers and footers, but now extend to the left & right edges.

If you want to recreate the side margins, you can use autolayout to adjust the width of the entire tableView, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016313/ios7-uitableview-grouped-like-in-settings-app)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a slight modification to [`UITableView`'s `UIViewTableStyleGrouped`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewStyleGrouped).

```
tableView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
```