# Update a Tableview cell mid rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios7

I have a tableview with cells with rounded corner. I used this method below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18833311

But when I rotate the device the rounded corners do not update. I have been able to reload the table after it rotates but it looks very bad during the rotation.

Any ideas on how to update the cell mid rotation or another idea?

Comment: have you tried [tableView reloadData] after you get the notification of rotation changed?

Comment: Yes, but this only updates after the rotation has finished rather than mid rotation so the rounded part does nothing until the end.
<code>- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}<code>