# Weird UITableViewCell selection in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am developing an app in **iOS7**. I have one `TableViewController`, it's style is grouped.
I successfully implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18833311) solution, can get curve to `TableView` as I want.

**EDIT:-** I am not using any custom class for cell. I have added `TableView` just from nib and also using by default cell.

Code implemented is as below :-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
        if (tableView == self.tblviwSample) {
            CGFloat cornerRadius = 5.f;
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
            CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
            CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);
            BOOL addLine = NO;
            if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
                CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
            } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
                addLine = YES;
            } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            } else {
                CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds);
                addLine = YES;
            }
            layer.path = pathRef;
            CFRelease(pathRef);
            layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.8f].CGColor;

            if (addLine == YES) {
                CALayer *lineLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
                CGFloat lineHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
                lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds)+10, bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width-10, lineHeight);
                lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor;
                [layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
            }
            UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
            [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
            testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
            cell.backgroundView = testView;
        }
    }
}
```

Effect of this code - [See this - before selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI9qa.png)

But getting one problem, when I select a cell, it's looking weird like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxgy4.png)

I want the section in proper manner. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I stumbled upon this problem just today as well. I've just changed the cell's `selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` until I find a solid solution. The cell received the selection but it doesn't highlight it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the tableview thinner (decrease width from both sides), then implement your looks so that the line would end not before edge of table view, but stretch all the way to the side of tableview.

In other words - decrease table view width to match current line width and leave the line as bid as it is now (it would then be as wide as tableview). Your selection will now be less wide too.

Or, upon selection you can modify your table view cell so that you mimic some custom selection. That could be from changing cell color up to flipping it with animations.

Comment: please be clear with the answer.it will be helpful if you can elaborate the answer

Comment: I do not understand what is there to be elaborated. You narrow table view to be as wide as line in provided image. Then selection will be as wide as lines too. Design does not require tableview to be as wide as whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem too today, and here's the fix:

add below code to the end of willDisplayCell:

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = cell.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = pathRef;
cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer.mask = maskLayer;

CFRelease(pathRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

When `UITableViewCells` are selected, all subviews get a `backgroundcolor` of `[UIColor clearColor]` by default, and the cells `selectedBackgroundView` is the one that sets how things are looking.

In your codesample, you are manipulating the bakcgroundview to get rounded corners, but as soon as a cell is selected this view becomes transparent. I would suggest overriding `setSelected`, and manipulating the cells subviews here.

From `UITableViewCells` `selectedBackgroundView` documentation:

> The default is nil for cells in plain-style tables
>   (UITableViewStylePlain) and non-nil for section-group tables
>   UITableViewStyleGrouped). UITableViewCell adds the value of this
>   property as a subview only when the cell is selected. It adds the
>   selected background view as a subview directly above the background
>   view (backgroundView) if it is not nil, or behind all other views.
>   Calling setSelected:animated: causes the selected background view to
>   animate in and out with an alpha fade.