# Creating the iOS Settings Menu

Tags: uitableview, ios7, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am going to have some settings in my application, and wanted to mirror the familiar style found within the iPhone itself (it looks like a standard tableview, but with grey areas that separate sections. the grey areas have text in them).

Is there any particular approach you are all aware of that I might try to do? For example would I create a uitableview with X prototype cells? Would it be something more involved, like multiple uitableviews for each "section", and color the background of the main screen grey?

Hope this makes sense. Essentially wanted to make it look like how 'settings' looks.

Thanks so much.

Comment: The iOS settings uses one UITableView but it has sections in it. It's all built into UITableView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 TableView like in Settings App on iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822619/ios-7-tableview-like-in-settings-app-on-ipad)