# Recreating and understanding iOS settings menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I would like to recreate the iOS settings menu. To do so I need to understand how this is created. Please find an example here below:

[image]

My understanding is that this is a masterdetailview controller style project with at the left a table view and at the right a detail view with custom cells.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822619/ios-7-tableview-like-in-settings-app-on-ipad) to recreate the grouping but have no idea yet on how to create the custom actions.

- How can I create a custom cell like the one below to adjust brightness (it has a **slider**)?
- How do you add a label like Apple does and a button? Do you have a separate xib file for each cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a custom UITableViewCell you should have a UITableView in your ViewController.

Then you can add Custom UITableViewCell by Adding a new file to the project.

[image]

Now you can see 3 files are added to the project. Go to the XIB file & modify it as you want. Finally Go to the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  method & add these lines in it.

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier"; //Set Identifier for cell

        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: MyIdentifier]; //init CustomCell

        if (cell == nil) { //Check cell is nill or not
            NSArray *nib;
            nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell"
                                                owner:self options:nil]; //if cell is nil add CustomCell Xib

            for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
                cell = (CustomCell *)oneObject;
        }

        //Set Cell Values Here

        return cell;
```