# Corner radius for table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to change the cell corner radius like in the below image:

[image]

Comment: i want to set corner like above image section 1

Comment: I don't thing this is possible on iOS

Answer (score 17):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
if (tableView == self.orderDetailsTableView)
{
    //Top Left Right Corners
    let maskPathTop = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
    let shapeLayerTop = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerTop.frame = cell.bounds
    shapeLayerTop.path = maskPathTop.CGPath

    //Bottom Left Right Corners
    let maskPathBottom = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
    let shapeLayerBottom = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerBottom.frame = cell.bounds
    shapeLayerBottom.path = maskPathBottom.CGPath

    //All Corners
    let maskPathAll = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight, .BottomRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
    let shapeLayerAll = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayerAll.frame = cell.bounds
    shapeLayerAll.path = maskPathAll.CGPath

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)-1)
    {
        cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerAll
    }
 else if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
    cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerTop
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)-1)
    {
        cell.layer.mask = shapeLayerBottom
    }
}
}
```

what actually we are doing is if section has only one row then we do it on all sides, if section has multiple rows then we do it top on first row and bottom at last row... the properties BottomLeft, BottomRight, topLeft, TopRight should be of type rect corner(Suggestions from xcode when you are typing... there is another property content corner with same name.. so check that )

Comment: This should be marked as the Correct Answer, at least it's what helped me :-)

Comment: @SaiPavanParanam thank you so much, after searching for days i lost hope and finally your solution works with slight modification to my scenario.

Comment: It's not woking at all please check in your view controller.

Comment: my app never gets inside the willDisplayCell. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 14):

You can use following code in swift 2.0

Put this code in cellForRowAtIndexpath method:

```
cell!.layer.cornerRadius=10 //set corner radius here
cell!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor  // set cell border color here
cell!.layer.borderWidth = 2 // set border width here
```

Below is the output of my code

[image]

Comment: If that doesn't work try `cell!.contentView.layer`. I suspect that it's the cell's content view that has the border and rounded corners, not the cell.

Comment: @DuncanC Please see my edited answer. this code is worked for me.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants a sectioned table view where the sections are grouped with a rounded rectangle around the whole section. That's more complicated.

Comment: I want to radius section of tableview cell not row of tableview cell see image above

Comment: I have no idea why this answer has more votes over mine

Comment: @SaiPavanParanam See the difference between both the code. you will get your answer. :)

Comment: @PallaviNikumbh  Your answer does not actually solve his question.

Comment: @PallaviNikumbh You are actually giving border to the entire Cell. He just needs it the section wise.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your tableView contains an `UIView` so just add these rows in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If not add an UIView and add the radius to the UIView and just add that view to your cell (`cell.addSubView(YOURVIEW)`).

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

To customize the border you can

```
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
cell.layer.borderWidth = 5
```

**Update**

To add this in your `viewForHeaderInSection`
Create a view let view = UIView() and add the radius to your view

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

And add other properties that you need and return that view.

Comment: it's set whole cell corner radius i want to set section wise

Comment: Then you need to add a viewForHeaderInSection to your tableView if you don´t already use it. Check the updated code.

Comment: i also try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822619/ios-7-tableview-like-in-settings-app-on-ipad but not work

Comment: Add your code to your question, then it´s easier to help you.

Comment: "but not work" is **NOT** helpful at all. You need to describe what you tried in detail, as well as how it did not meet your needs, *also in detail*.

Answer (score 1):

I was setting `contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10` and it was still not showing; this was due to the `cell.contentView.backgroundColor` defaulting to `nil` which results in a transparent background color, thus it has `cell.backgroundColor` as it's bkgColor.

Setting the Cell's background color to `.clear`, which in my case would show the tableView's background color (non-white), it would then show the corner radius as desired, like this:

```
// Cell's init()
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        backgroundColor = .clear // this will show parent views bkgColor 
                                 //(in my case non-white) 
                                 // where the sharp corner is

        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0 // set corner radius
        contentView.backgroundColor = .white // set tableViewCells background color to what you want

        /* do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

in your TableViewCell

or:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
cell.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is to change corner radius in awakeFromNib and make sure to set its clipToBounds to true.

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
self.clipToBounds = true
```

Or you can place a view inside your cell as background view and set its corner radius and clipToBounds.

```
self.backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
self.backgroundView.clipToBounds = true
```