# Cell image view cornerRadius in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Where would I best set the cornerRadius property?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 1/6 * tableView.bounds.width
}
```

I have tried it in the cell's awakeFromNib, but it doesn't yet seem to have the proper height.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454924/set-tableview-cell-corner-radius-swift-2-0 
This is what you need.

Comment: @Latcie are you talking about cell height or corner radius?

Answer (score 4):

If the image view size if flexible and the corner radius is linked to the image size, I advise you to set the corner radius in the `layoutSubviews()` method of your cell.

You can set it as following:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2.0
}
```

Comment: Even when this is called the first time, it doesn't seem to be able to get the correct imageView.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Okay **warning - all untested code**

If you assume that the object which knows best how to draw a cell, is the cell itself....

Create a subclass of the Cell

```
class MyUITableViewCell: UITableViewCell
```

Now, there are many ways to skin this cell. My preference is to:

Add a method for all of the little things you wish to change in the cell

```
func configure () {

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0 // for instance

}
```

When should you call configure?

Arguably you could call in in draw() but I like to

Call configure() via the delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if cell.responds(to: #selector(MyUITableViewCell.configure()) {

        cell.configure()

    }
}
```