# UITableView section shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to achieve the tableView section shadow in UITableViewController.

Comment: You want this shadow in the section header write? or in the whole section

Comment: Not in section header. I want shadow in whole section. Check the image attached above those are separate sections.

Comment: Found a way to achieve it. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822619/ios-7-tableview-like-in-settings-app-on-ipad)

Answer (score 9):

Add this method to get drop shadow of UITableView Section
This answer is in Swift3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let shadowView = UIView()
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame.size = CGSize(width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 15)

    let stopColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor    
    let startColor = UIColor.white.cgColor    

    gradient.colors = [stopColor, startColor]    
    gradient.locations = [0.0,0.8]

    shadowView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)    

    return shadowView
}
```

Comment: What is myTab??

Comment: the question is about the section NOT section header or footer only!