# Reload round rectangle groupped tableview in Landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview, reload, landscape

I am using Boris's answer (objective-C) for [custom tableview with round rectangle border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079113/border-around-uitableview-section).

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlC0H.png)

It is working fine. It shows border around my custom tableView cells. When I rotate device in landscape mode then it also rotates but doesn't auto-resize border.

I also have a sliding menu that opens tableview screen. If I open tableview screen again in landscape mode using sliding menu button then it redraws cell border before cell appears and shows border correctly in landscape mode.  So I know it appears correctly in landscape mode too but only when it reloads screen.

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAnKW.png)

It should also redraw it upon rotation.I am trying to achieve it from last 2 days but it is not working anyhow.  I tried to call willDisplayCell method manually  in landscape mode but no success. I tried to refresh and reload tableView but none worked.

How do I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you post screenshot of the TableView Constraint in the question so that it can get more clear

Comment: I am creating tableview programmatically. The only thing I did in storyboard is that I added a group tableview with a cell. I am not using auto layout and using autoresizing. I have no constraints in my code or tableView storyboard screen because I am not using auto layout.

Comment: try to put background color and check wether the color is spreading in landscape mode or not

Comment: yes I have tried that already and It is spreading correctly.

Comment: if you can show how is the output then i can help you

Comment: okey, You can upload screenshot on any other website and paste here url also.

Comment: This looks fine

Comment: I just noticed that when I scroll tableview up and down in landscape mode then it refreshes any cell that goes out of screen first and appears on screen again. It shows those cells correctly (but not other cells that don't leave screen). I just need to refresh or reload complete tableview screen like it is being opened first time.