# Adding background for TableView sections iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, background-image, sections

I have a section with dynamic multiple rows and I need to separate all the section with the background as shown in the image below.

Specifically those border lines for all the section. Pease let me know how can I make it possible.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{
    return  ProductArray.count;  
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *arr = [ProductArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return arr.count;    
}
```

Please refer to this

[image].

I tried adding header and footer, But I am not understanding how to add that rectangle box image for the entire section.

Comment: Please include examples of what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can take a UIView in cell with corner Radius or color.

Comment: Please take a look at [Border around UITableView Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079113/border-around-uitableview-section)

Answer (score 0):

Put View in your cell after make outlet of that view. And use to **cellForRowAtIndexPath** this method.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    cell.viewBackGround.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For above requirement, I would like to suggest you the below approach.

create only one section with multiple rows.

1. Each row of `UITableView` will have `UITableViewCell`
2. Inside `UITableViewCell` create content view for which we are gonna add the border
3. Each row of `UITableViewCell` will have another `UITableView`(inside content view) whose methods are handled by `UITableViewCell` cells
4. Change `UITableView` (inside) height based on number of rows.
5. provide height of `UITableViewCell` based on the number of rows + orderID Header.